# How to update uilabel text in response swift 4

Tags: swift, closures, uilabel, swift4, urlsession

I try to update label.text with server response. But label is updated only after second call of method. What is wrong?

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) is deprecated. I changed it to DispatchQueue.main.async, but it does not work.

Example for swift 2:
[Swift changing text of a label after downloading content of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29220877/1358978)

Not working code:

```swift
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=2005-2-22&api_key=DEMO_KEY")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data,
            let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("stringData: \(stringData)") // prints every time

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // change label text after second calling.
                // ??? How to change label text at first calling ???
                self?.mainLabel.text = stringData
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Check whether `mainLabel` is nil while first call?

Comment: mainLabel != nil. it is IBOutlet

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var labelString : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.mainLabel.text = labelString
        }
    }
```

Write below code inside buttonAction

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // change label text after second calling.
       // ??? How to change label text at first calling ???
        self?.labelString = stringData
  }
```

Comment: It works on simulator, but with 3-5 seconds delay. And not every time. But why?
Version from question works on device but don't work on simulator.